# How to read a transaction in human readable format using web3?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, etherscan, etherjs

I am using Alchemy API as my web3 provider and got a transaction data like this below:

```js
{
  blockHash: null,
  blockNumber: null,
  from: '0xa12e1462d0ced572f396f58b6e2d03894cd7c8a4',
  gas: '0x440f0',
  gasPrice: '0x3b9aca000',
  hash: '0x4e4d44a84404dbaff0d96357729d732a204a4b4e924bb1cccd1173018e33e229',
  input: '0x7ff36ab500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c95a8b7d8bf0e2000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000048c04ed5691981c42154c6167398f95e8f38a7ff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006391cc960000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc20000000000000000000000007db5af2b9624e1b3b4bb69d6debd9ad1016a58ac',
  nonce: '0x1dc3',
  to: '0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d',
  transactionIndex: null,
  value: '0x20db9bccc4e8cb1',
  type: '0x0',
  chainId: '0x1',
  v: '0x25',
  r: '0x461d8ff7fa9920577a428a6433e4a6f7a6dbfb6678952ee26638e8e2ad3fa6a3',
  s: '0x35bdf93cffe336c178a81432f9adc4f40ff1eeb665673cc027f494f726ae1308'
}
```

I would like to know how to convert `gas` and `value` from a hash (e.g. `0x3b9aca000`) to `Gwei` or `ether`.

Like in etherscan, this transaction's details are in a human readable format. I would like to know how to achieve it in API
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4e4d44a84404dbaff0d96357729d732a204a4b4e924bb1cccd1173018e33e229
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not difficult. try this.

To convert the gas and value fields from a hash to `Gwei` or Ether, you can use the web3.utils.fromWei() method provided by the Web3 library. This method takes the value in Wei (the smallest unit of Ether) and converts it to the specified unit. For example, to convert the gasPrice value from the transaction data you provided to `Gwei`, you could use the following code:

```
const gasPriceInGwei = web3.utils.fromWei(transactionData.gasPrice, 'gwei');
```

Similarly, to convert the value field to Ether, you can use the following code:

```
const valueInEther = web3.utils.fromWei(transactionData.value, 'ether');
```

You can then use the `gasPriceInGwei` and valueInEther variables to display the values in a human-readable format in your application.

Comment: Thank you @david, it works as my expectation. Just one question - is the `hash` itself in the unit of `wei`?

Comment: use your code as example, the value `0x3b9aca000` is not a hash. It is a hexadecimal number that represents the gas price of a transaction on the Ethereum blockchain. 

Gas original value is typically specified in Wei, the smallest unit of Ether, but now in your  showed code it was encoded in hexadecimal format for convenience.